# Does C# know to optimize Null Conditional Operators in multiple condition statements?

Tags: c#, optimization, null, operators

I have the following code:

```
var reportDate = (model.From?.Year == null || model.From?.Month == null || model.From?.Day == null) ? 
    DateTime.UtcNow.Date : 
    new DateTime(model.From.Year.Value, model.From.Month.Value, model.From.Day.Value);
```

Note the conditional expression, is it better to write

```
(model.From == null || model.From.Year == null || model.From.Month == null || model.From.Day == null)
```

so their won't be a `model.From` null check for every performed `==` operator? Does the compiler know how to optimize the former code to only check for `model.From` for null only once?

Comment: It can't do that.  What if `.From` has side-effects or can change?

Comment: @SLaks yeah, that is a good reason not to. Why could I not think about that before.